# Using Visual C++ for C++ instead of C++/CLI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++-cli

I know how to program in C++ making console programs, but now I want to code programs with interfaces for Windows. MS VS 2010 makes things easy when coding C++ Windows applications with its drag & drop design system. (.net Framework) However, Visual Studio seems to use C++/CLI, which I'm unfamiliar with.

**Is there for an IDE which only uses C++? Is there any good IDE with an easy to use GUI designer, or can I tweak VS 2010 to not to use C++/CLI?**

Comment: Find some scissors and cut the umbilical mouse cord.  Only way to become a Real C++ Programmer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual C++ is perfectly happy to not use C++/CLI syntax, in fact it works even better without it.

Just set "Use of .NET Framework (/clr)" setting in your project options to "No".  Or use the "Win32 Application" wizard when creating your project to begin with.

The "native" version of the Forms Designer is called the Dialog Editor and it works much the same way -- you can select textboxes and buttons and things from a palette and drag where you want them in your window.

Comment: When i disable /clr, drag & drop system stays the same and generates codes which are in C++/CLI syntax. Also, when i use Win32 Project option, i can't use toolbox options.

Comment: @gcx: Start with menu option "Project > Add New Resource > Dialog".  That will put you into the native UI designer.  There is no setting to make the .NET designer write native code, but there IS a native UI designer in Visual C++.  It's not the same editor but it works the same way.  I thought I explained that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about Qt Creator - IDE for Qt? http://www.qt.io/ide/

Answer (score 1):

The best RAD C++ tool, which also happens to accept unmanaged C++ is "CodeGear C++ Builder"