# Create a forms application with Visual Studio without CLR/.NET

Tags: .net, c++, winforms, visual-c++, forms

I'm desperately trying to program a small chat program. But I'm not failing at the sockets / background logic as one might expect, but at the form containing the input and output text field!

Visual Studio offers a forms designer, however if I want to use it I have to use the CLR, .NET and precompiled headers apparently. It forces me to use it. I don't want that.

- How can I in the most simple way, without .NET, add a form to my C++ project?
- Are there any good tutorials you can recommend for me?

Even if I don't sound like it, I'm a relatively experienced programmer - I just can't stand precompiled headers, .NET and most other Microsoft stuff. It makes me nervous.

Comment: Maybe you ought to try Qt and something other than Visual Studio.

Comment: I just want to get two text fields that I can read out and modify as fast as possible.. learning Qt now would be a bit much for me. I want to be finished as soon as possible with the project

Comment: thats what VS10 is for..remember RAD..

Comment: If you want to do it quickly, then just use CLR instead of trying to figure out how to work against, rather than with, Visual Studio.

Comment: @siride: Didn't Nokia just announce end-of-life for Qt?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual C++ without C++/CLI Syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572116/visual-c-without-c-cli-syntax) which despite the title is focused on native UI designers.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: it hasn't been EOLed, but the new plan with MS and WP7 does make the future look shaky.

Answer (score 1):

You can use MFC or good ol' Win32 API (not really good, just ol'), both of these completely bypass .NET Framework and CLR

Comment: Win32 design has stood the test of time, much more elegant than Java, .NET, or MFC APIs.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: disagree strongly.  It has stood the test of time, but not due to elegance in any way, shape or form.

Comment: @siride: Come back and say that after you've written async I/O code in both Win32 and Linux, or Win32 and any of the "modern" options mentioned above.  `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` is an elegant API and nothing else compares.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: That function is pretty similar to select()/poll() on Unix systems.  But one good function does not make for an elegant API.

Comment: Except that `select` can only be used with the first 64 or so file descriptors, `poll` can't be used to wait for processes or threads or mutexes or ...  `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx` may be just a single function, but it's representative of the way integration of all kernel objects with user interface events makes it really easy to develop a single-threaded non-blocking event-driven application, which is optimal for a very large class of applications.  And when you do move to multiple threads, you can feed cross-thread messages through the same mechanism and guarantee consistency of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only the Express Edition, then you have a problem.  Best approach if you don't have money for tools would be to download another IDE with a designer for e.g. wxWindows and configure it to run the MS compiler.

With VS2010 Professional or higher, there's a native designer, called the dialog editor, which provides drag-and-drop layout much like the WinForms designer does.