# How can I design windows in Visual C++ without CLR?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I'd like to rewrite a VB.NET(2010) project in C++. I have a basic knowledge of C++ from books and lessons, but it's mostly about syntax and console apps and I struggle to create a UI.
I need a UI designer  (with basic common controls + tab and chart, database connection would be great but I could do without). I want to write in C++ (not C++/CLI) but none of the clr-less options I've tested in VS2010 or 2015 come with a UI designer.
 Is there *any* way to use a designer without .net framework/clr?

Comment: Yes... There is the Windows API... But it is **very** hard... You can use the MFC or the WTL to abstract a little of it... But it is stille **very** hard. There are various frameworks (for example QT) that are easier to use (and that are more complete as the number of widgets they have). The Windows API is a little poor of widgets.

Comment: Another option is to use C++/CX and program a WinRT app... It will only run on Windows >= 8

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this response: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/4572131/660711)

I think it might suit you because it helps you build a UI using only C++.

As stated in the comments, it uses the Windows API, which might be hard, but it lets you drag & drop, for example.

To start, click File->New Project and choose Win33 Project. Then, use the "Win32 Application" wizard.

(I would put this into a comment if I had sufficient reputation)

Comment: Thanks. I've tried this but it doesn't seem to allow use of the chart control which I need. Anyway, I don't know enough about API programming to design my project this way.